# switch between 3 monitors setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, cmd.exe

Is there any way of switching between 3 monitors setup ( enable, disable, extend ) using cmd?

The command `DisplaySwitch.exe /internal, /external, /extend` seems to work with only 2 monitors setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the following free third-party utilities for saving
and restoring monitor setup. Even if the utilities don't work to save
the entire state in one go, you can use them in a script that will
operate on the individual monitors.

- [MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
- [DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK)

Comment: Tnx. I didn't know about DesktopOK.

Any method without using third-party utilities?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: not without accessing the winapi directly